# How to get certain SQL query results at the top of the list

Tags: sql, linq

I'm convinced this will make me slap myself when I see the answer but here goes...

Say I need a list of all products from a certain vendor but they need to order by a specific variable productType at the top and below it doesn't really matter but all products have to be in the list.

So basically

```
SELECT * FROM Products p WHERE p.VendorID = 1 AND p.ProductType = 'widget'
```

as the first rows to display.  Then,

```
SELECT * FROM Products p WHERE p.VendorID = 1 AND p.ProductType <> 'widget'
```

underneath that.

I'm using LINQ if that helps any but I can't even get this in regular SQL queries

Comment: And that doesn't work? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I union those it doesn't maintain the order with the first query on top.  Also this is a simplified example of a much larger query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products p
WHERE p.VendorID = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN p.ProductType = 'widget' THEN 1 ElSE 2 END
```

And in Linq:

```
IQueryable<Product> query =
  from p in dc.Products
  where p.VendorID == 1
  orderby p.ProductType == "widget" ? 1 : 2
  select p;
```

Comment: Thanks, wrote it in query analyzer so it looked ok. :)  Editted.

Answer (score 3):

One option is:

```
SELECT *, 
        CASE p.ProductType WHEN 'widget' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ProductPriority 
    FROM Products p 
    WHERE p.VendorID = 1 
    ORDER BY ProductPriority
```

Comment: This worked well too but I only get to pick one answer.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I think you picked the right answer (I voted the other answer up).

Answer (score 2):

Create an extra field in the select part that indicates if they should be on top. For instance.

```
SELECT *, (p.ProductType = 'widget') AS thisfirst  FROM Products p WHERE p.VendorID = 1 ORDER BY thisfirst
```

Comment: That won't work in SQL Server and many dbs. You must use a Case function (or if Access (bleh), an IIF function).

Comment: For mysql this seems correct to me (haven't ran it though). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal
Of course with an if or case you can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just order by a case statement like so:

```
select * from products
order by case producttype when 'widget' then 1 end nulls last;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using LINQ to SQL, so I think it would be better to do this using a LINQ query:

```
db.Products
  .Where(p => p.VendorID == 1)
  .OrderBy(p => p.ProductType == 'widget')
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to Brian's would be a union query:

```
Select ...
From    (
        Select ..., 0 As SortOrder
        from Products
        Where VendorId = 1
            And ProductType = 'Widget'
        Union All 
        Select ..., 1
        from Products
        Where VendorId = 1
            And ProductType <> 'Widget'
        ) As Z
Order By Z.SortOrder
```

Comment: I concur - using UNION is easy and allows the use of possible ORDER BY clauses in conjunction.

Comment: This incurs two accesses to the Products table when only one is required. If the table is large, this will not perform well.

Comment: This query will exclude rows where ProductType is null.

Comment: @David B: Granted. Although the OP does not provide schema so we have no means of A: knowing if it is nullable or B: if the query should return nulls.